# Need some clearing up with function calls

Tags: python, function, parameters, execution

I'm currently doing some review for my exam, and I have a strange problem or I might be overseeing an extremely simple mistake that I for some reason can't catch. I'm practicing with functions and parameter passing between these functions, and I whipped up a really simple program to make sure I understood the basics:

```
 def temperature(celsius, fahrenheit):
      celsius = 15
      fahrenheit = 59
      print("The current temperature in C is: ", celsius)
      print("The current temperature in F is: ", fahrenheit)
      return(celsius, fahrenheit)

 temperature(celsius, fahrenheit)
```

Now I'm not sure if the return values are needed, but I put them there because I remember my professor saying it's important.

Now, the issue is when I try to run this, it tells me that the variables that should be passing are not even recognized when the program runs. Can someone explain why this is the issue?

And for future reference, if I wanted to pass these variables between 2 or more functions, how will I do that?

**UPDATE: ADDING FOLLOWING TEXT FOR FURTHER CLARIFICATION**

Here's some code my professor provided me with as an exemplar. How does he pass those local variables?

```
def introduction ():
    print ("""
Celsius to Fahrenheit converter
-------------------------------
This program will convert a given Celsius temperature to an equivalent
Fahrenheit value.

    """)

def display(celsius, fahrenheit):
    print("")
    print("Celsius value: ", celsius)
    print("Fahrenheit value:", fahrenheit)

def convert():
    celsius = float(input("Type in the celsius temperature: "))
    fahrenheit = celsius * (9 / 5) + 32
    display(celsius, fahrenheit)

def start():
    introduction ()
    convert ()

start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You have a problem understanding how functions work ...*

The scope of the variables defined within a function does not exceed the function itself. That is to say, if you get out of the function, these variables (if they are not global) do not exist anymore.

You should either **define the variables** before calling the function, or pass them as **keyword arguments** to give them values by default:

```
celsius = 15
fahrenheit = 59
def temperature(celsius, fahrenheit):
      print("The current temperature in C is: ", celsius)
      print("The current temperature in F is: ", fahrenheit)
      return(celsius, fahrenheit)
```

and call it like this :

```
temperature(celsius, fahrenheit)
```

Or using keywords :

```
def temperature(celsius=15, fahrenheit=59):
      print("The current temperature in C is: ", celsius)
      print("The current temperature in F is: ", fahrenheit)
      return(celsius, fahrenheit)
```

Calling it like this :

```
temperature() # --> use the default parameters
#or 
temperature(celsius=0, fahrenheit=10) --> change the values of your parameters
```

But in both ways, there is no need to overwrite the variables within the function as you've done.

---

**Update** :

The value of the variable `celsius` is set by the user when typing the value of the variable in the console :

```
celsius = float(input("Type in the celsius temperature: "))
```

*What does the function `convert()` do ?* :

```
def convert():
     celsius = float(input("Type in the celsius temperature: ")) #<-- set the value of the variable to that entered by the user thanks to input()
     fahrenheit = celsius * (9 / 5) + 32 # <-- creates the variable from celsius
     display(celsius, fahrenheit) # <-- calls the display function with celsius and fahrenheit being well defined
```

`input` takes the value entered by the user as a `string`, then he casts it to an `int`.

Comment: I'll put it in the edited version of the post then if you don't mind!

Comment: cf 'Update' section

Comment: So display simply displays the inputs made by the user in the convert function. So we should make new variables and call the function we want the values "transported" to for lack of a better term?

Comment: What do you mean by : `So we should make new variables and call the function we want the values "transported" to`

Comment: Like in convert(), celsius and fahrenheit are defined as input in the function. So if we wanted to access those values in another function, should we always assign a new variable to a value before passing it over to the other function? I'm sorry if I don't make sense, I don't know how to word my stuff properly.

Comment: You can also use global variables

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification on everything. I feel more confident about functions!

Comment: @SatinderpalSaroa What about an upvote and a validation then ? haha

Answer (score 0):

Before calling temperature(celsius, fahrenheit) you need to define the variables celsius and fahrenheit.

For instance:

```
def temperature(celsius, fahrenheit):
    celsius = 15
    fahrenheit = 59
    print("The current temperature in C is: ", celsius)
    print("The current temperature in F is: ", fahrenheit)
    return(celsius, fahrenheit)

celsius = 20   
fahrenheit = 15

temperature(celsius, fahrenheit)
```

Then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error, because the scope of variable that you have declared 'celsius' and 'farenheit' are local to the function temparature(), you should declare it outside the function so that their scope is not limited.

```
 def temperature(celsius, fahrenheit):
  print("The current temperature in C is: ", celsius)
  print("The current temperature in F is: ", fahrenheit)
  return(celsius, fahrenheit)

celsius = 15
fahrenheit = 59
temperature(celsius, fahrenheit)
```